# In Ember, how to keep parent route's model consistent with child routes?

Tags: ember.js

Here are my routes:

```
this.resource('kb_obj', {path: '/kb/:data_type'}, function() {
  this.resource('kb_obj_show', {path: '/:id'}, function() {
    this.route('with_breadcrumb', {path: '/:breadcrumb'});
  });
  this.resource('kb_filtered_page', {path: '/:filter_params/page/:page_id'}, function() {
    this.route('index', {path: '/'});
  });
});
```

As you can see, the KbObjRoute's main job is to store the current data type.

My problem is that when someone clicks a link such as this:

```
{{#linkTo 'kb_obj_show.with_breadcrumb' this this}}{{name}}{{/linkTo}}
```

The `model` or `setupController` methods are not fired on the KbObjRoute, so it never gets to update its data type and anything that depends on that info (e.g. the main nav links) don't get updated.

I can't see how to notify the parent route of what's going on with its children.

Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the parent resource (kb_obj_show) and the child route (with_breadcrumb) the same model?  Just curious since you're sending in this twice in your link-to

Answer (score 0):

I think there might be two misconceptions here

1. your sub-routes build on the parent route but don't modify it (more
   below)  perhaps there is a mismatch with what you are trying to achieve
   and the URL structure
2. the model method won't be called for a linkTo (because the
   linkTo is supplying the model).  if someone drops directly into the 
   route they will be called

The URL `/kb/image` might load a bunch of images as the model.  `/kb/image/123` is one of those images.  Changing `123`'s data_type isn't going to bubble up and change the dynamic segment.

That being said, routes and controllers can depend on eachother in a few ways.

With routes, you can use the [`modelFor`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_modelFor) method, in your case I think it would be:

```
this.modelFor('kb_obj')
```

With controllers you would use the `needs` array.  So if you wanted to get a model or property from another controller you can do that:

```
App.SubController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  needs: "otherController",
  linkedProperty: Ember.computed.alias("controllers.otherController.model.itsProperty")
});
```